# Получение массива значений из массива объектов

Tags: массивы, php

Суть: часто в коде оказывается массив объектов, а на обработку надо передать массив целочисленных значений определённого поля.
Сделал велосипед:

```
private function getProperty($arrayObjects, $propertyName)
{
    if (is_object($arrayObjects) && is_string($propertyName))
    {
        $property = NULL;
        foreach ($arrayObjects as $object)
        {
            $property[] = $object->$propertyName;
        }
        return $property;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Неверный тип данных");
    }
}
```

Но, чёрт подери, должен же быть **более простой способ** :(

Comment: На самом деле я уже нашёл способ избежать этого бреда, но вопрос остаются.

Comment: Вполне симпатично, на мой взгляд. Хотите непременно меньше строк? =)

Comment: надеялся на существование нативной функции в самом php, но не нашёл

Comment: [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй, только [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$test = array(
    (object)array('id' => 1,'x' => 5),
    (object)array('id' => 2,'x' => 6),
    (object)array('id' => 3,'x' => 7),
);

$propertyName = 'x';
$values = function($o) use ($propertyName) {
    return $o->$propertyName;
};
$result = array_map($values, $test);

print_r( $result);

/*  Вывод:
    Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 7
    )
*/
```

<strike>Upd. Явно можно написать лаконичнее и красивее, понимаю.</strike>

**Upd.2**: Closures!

Comment: Плюсую. Хотя на счёт лаконичности согласен.

Comment: Исправил, 5 строк )